# Using a string-formatted numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Given: a numpy array created from a string:

```
xy = np.array('4.9 3.5; 5.1 3.2; 4.7 3.1; 4.6 3.0; 5.0 5.4')
```

First off: is there a specific *name* for this construct?

Here is the *datatype*:

```
In [25]: xy
Out[25]:
array('4.9 3.5; 5.1 3.2; 4.7 3.1; 4.6 3.0; 5.0 5.4',
      dtype='|S43')
```

What *is* `|S43` ..

So OK enough with internals..  So here is the real question:   how do we *use* the generated array:

```
In [31]: cov(xy)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-6d999a60c1da> in <module>()
----> 1 cov(xy)

  .. 
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

That result *contrasts* with the more standard usage of `np.array`:

```
In [33]: xy = np.array([[4.9, 3.5],[5.1, 3.2],[ 4.7, 3.1],[ 4.6, 3.0],[ 5.0, 5.4]], dtype=float)

In [35]: cov(xy)
Out[35]:
array([[ 0.98 ,  1.33 ,  1.12 ,  1.12 , -0.28 ],
       [ 1.33 ,  1.805,  1.52 ,  1.52 , -0.38 ],
       [ 1.12 ,  1.52 ,  1.28 ,  1.28 , -0.32 ],
       [ 1.12 ,  1.52 ,  1.28 ,  1.28 , -0.32 ],
       [-0.28 , -0.38 , -0.32 , -0.32 ,  0.08 ]])
```

So .. how to use the stringified `numpy.array` syntax to get that same result?

**Update** My bad here: i was mixing up `numpy.array` with `numpy.matrix`. The latter one *does* support the stringified syntax. See my answer below.

Comment: The `|S43` means your type is a String with 43 chars

Comment: `dtype='|S43'` indicates that the array is a `string` array of length `43` (it has 43 characters).  In other words, it is storing everything as a string, not as numbers.

Comment: You can't compute the covariance of a string. You have to use numbers (int, float ...) for computation.

Comment: `can't compute cov of a string` . Yea no kidding .. The assumption were that `numpy` performs the conversion.  Maybe I am mixing up `R` with numpy, checking ..

Comment: The numpy array doesn't perform the conversion. Numpy arrays are generic types to store data of the same type. The type can be a string. In your case you create an array that contains one element (one string).

Comment: I'm trying to find which language/tool were doing the conversion automatically using the `;` to separate the rows. Not making this up .. just not remembering at this moment either. *Found it*:  `numpy.matrix`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem: I was mixing `numpy.array` with `numpy.matrix`.

```
In [47]: np.matrix('1 2 3; 4 5 6')
Out[47]:
matrix([[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6]])
```

Comment: Yes, this input style was added to `np.matrix` to give MATLAB users something familiar.   Add a `.A` to make an array.  Of course it's only useful for toy examples.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the string to a usable format **before** passing it to `numpy.array`.  Try this:

```
# original string
xy_str = '4.9 3.5; 5.1 3.2; 4.7 3.1; 4.6 3.0; 5.0 5.4'

# break into nested lists, pass to numpy.array
xy = numpy.array([list(map(float, v.split())) for v in  xy_str.split('; ')])
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the string into a list of lists like what's in your correct example.

```
orig_xy_str = '4.9 3.5; 5.1 3.2; 4.7 3.1; 4.6 3.0; 5.0 5.4'
new_xy = np.array([vals.split(' ') for vals in orig_xy_string.split('; ')], dtype=float)

>>> np.cov(new_xy)
array([[ 0.98 ,  1.33 ,  1.12 ,  1.12 , -0.28 ],
       [ 1.33 ,  1.805,  1.52 ,  1.52 , -0.38 ],
       [ 1.12 ,  1.52 ,  1.28 ,  1.28 , -0.32 ],
       [ 1.12 ,  1.52 ,  1.28 ,  1.28 , -0.32 ],
       [-0.28 , -0.38 , -0.32 , -0.32 ,  0.08 ]])
```

If you have no control over the initial input (as you say you are "given a numpy array created from a string"), first convert the array to a string with `orig_xy_str = str(xy)`